# can I use hebrew in Google glass speech recognition?

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I read here there are 2 types of voice commands in glass:

1) choosing from a menu (e.g. "ok glass, directions to")

2) free speech recognition (e.g. "fifth avenue NYC")

I want **develop** a glass app and want to use voice recognition.

which of them can i use non-English language?

I talk developer-wise to change the language not user-wise.

Meaning saying "Ok Glass" and then menu items are in hebrew

or "take me to" and then place description in hebrew.

Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

At this point Glass voice recognition appears to only support US English.  The "Ok Glass" menu items are controlled by Google for official apps.  It is my understanding that the classifiers that recognize these commands are included in the Glass code, not just recognized using the string.  (Side loaded apps can have their own voice command based on an English string but it isn't as reliable as the ones Google has officially endorsed.

Free speech recognition for example when you reply to an email in Glass is done using the RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent.  While Android documentation suggests one could add the extra parameter to the intent of EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Glass itself only handle's English.

Therefore if you want to workaround this you will need to use the MediaRecorder and grab the audio directly, stream it to a service providing Hebrew Voice to Text transcription and then send the text back to your Glass application.  This would not be supported directly from the clock, you'd have to either handle it from a LiveCard or an Immersion. Glass will display Hebrew characters.